# Display Report in Visualforce - Without Iframe

Tags: report, visualforce

My requirement is to build custom Dashboards in Visualforce page and upon clicking drill down to another Visualforce page which shows the corresponding report. I have built the dasboards using google charts and it is cool. Now the toughest part is how to display the reports in Visualforce page. I tried using the  but seems it display on the report chart and not the report. Now my question is - is there a way to display the report at all or should i go for JQUERY Page to create and render a report. Thanks for the pointers.